# Need help selecting appropriate statistical method for animal study

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, mixed-model

I could use some help deciding on the proper statistical method for a current experiment. The experiment is setup as follows:

Independent Variable: Diet (4 groups of 10 for a total of 40 animals)
Dependent Variable: Body weight (Measured 3X/week for 3 weeks)

I would like to know whether there is a significant difference within and between groups, as well as at which points in time. I was looking at the [R-blogger tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-two-way-repeated-measures-anova/) to do two-way repeated measures ANOVA in R, but the setup doesn't seem to allow for the measurement of the group effect. Assuming I can get this figured out, I would like to do the same for glucose and insulin tolerance tests, which would have a similar data setup.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: FWIW, I think this question should be considered on topic here. The Q explicitly asks about which statistical method to use, which is within our mandate. Although it mentions R, it isn't clear that it is asking for coding help.

Comment: Gung is correct. I just want help choosing a statistical method. I think I will be able to implement it in R myself.

Comment: When you say you "would like to know whether there is a significant difference within ... groups," are you asking whether there are differences in the _rate of change_ of body weight among individuals placed on the same diet, or something else? Also, are you interested in comparing all individuals in the same group against each other, or just estimating the overall variability among the individuals?

Comment: EdM what I would like to know is (1) Within a particular group are the weights significantly different over time (2) Are the weights significantly different between groups (3) and if so at which time points.

Answer (score 1):

Mixed effects model may be applied here with diet and time as fixed effects and animal_id as random effect. You can use interaction term * rather than + to see effect of different combinations of diet and time. Following is an example output of a small simulated dataset (using 9 animals, 3 diets and 3 time points):

```
> summary(lmer(value~diet*time+(1|animal), data=mm))
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['merModLmerTest']
Formula: value ~ diet * time + (1 | animal)
   Data: mm

REML criterion at convergence: 83

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9458 -0.5076  0.0000  0.6345  1.8612 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 animal   (Intercept) 0.000    0.000   
 Residual             1.725    1.313   
Number of obs: 27, groups:  animal, 9

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate            Std. Error                    df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.666666666666667851  1.158258946008288159 21.000000000000000000   4.892 0.0000773 ***
diet        -0.333333333333334203  0.536169706477921837 21.000000000000000000  -0.622    0.5408    
timet2       1.555555555555554026  1.638025510184886402 21.000000000000000000   0.950    0.3531    
timet3       2.999999999999999112  1.638025510184887734 21.000000000000000000   1.831    0.0813 .  
diet:timet2  0.000000000000001138  0.758258470634678106 21.000000000000000000   0.000    1.0000    
diet:timet3 -0.333333333333332482  0.758258470634678661 21.000000000000000000  -0.440    0.6647    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) diet   timet2 timet3 dt:tm2
diet        -0.926                            
timet2      -0.707  0.655                     
timet3      -0.707  0.655  0.500              
diet:timet2  0.655 -0.707 -0.926 -0.463       
diet:timet3  0.655 -0.707 -0.463 -0.926  0.500
>
```

Dataset:

```
   animal diet time value
1       1    1   t1     5
2       2    1   t1     6
3       3    1   t1     5
4       4    2   t1     6
5       5    2   t1     5
6       6    2   t1     4
7       7    3   t1     5
8       8    3   t1     5
9       9    3   t1     4
10      1    1   t2     6
11      2    1   t2     8
12      3    1   t2     7
13      4    2   t2     9
14      5    2   t2     6
15      6    2   t2     4
16      7    3   t2     8
17      8    3   t2     5
18      9    3   t2     6
19      1    1   t3     9
20      2    1   t3     6
21      3    1   t3     8
22      4    2   t3     7
23      5    2   t3     8
24      6    2   t3     9
25      7    3   t3     6
26      8    3   t3     5
27      9    3   t3     8
```

Comment: Thank you @rnso. I don't have experience with mixed models. If you know of any, could you point me to some more information on them so I could read up. I am especially interested in validation of their use in animal studies.

Comment: Just google for it. Wiki page to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance